# Hows to do nested navigation with react-md?

Tags: react-md

Looking at the react-md component library, there are clear examples on how to draw a list of navigation items, including with dividers.

However I CAN'T find an example of how to use nested lists such as in the image pasted here. Using the `<NavigationDrawer>` components, what format should the `navItems` property be to get a nested list?

The documentation shows that this property should be an array of items that are either react elements or objects.

```
arrayOf(oneOfType([
  element,
    shape({
    divider: bool,
    subheader: bool,
    primaryText: node
  })
]))
```

Or... what other combinations of components could work?

[image: Nested navigation example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<ListItem>` component has a property `nestedItems`, which results in an expansion list. So it's nothing to do with the `<NavigationDrawer>` component.